# Telerik MVC 3.0 DatePicker dosen't seems to work While Binding to a Collection?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, datepicker, telerik-mvc

In my MVC 3.0 Razor Engine Project

I am using Telerik DatePicker
It seems to be Telerik Date Picker is having some issues while binding to Collections.
as mentioned [here on Telerik Forum](http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/aspnet-mvc/datepicker/datepicker-doesn-t-work-when-binding-to-a-collection.aspx#1869443)

This is my Code

```
@(Html.Telerik().DatePicker()
    .Name(ViewData.TemplateInfo.GetFullHtmlFieldName(string.Empty))
        .HtmlAttributes(new
        {
            id = ViewData.TemplateInfo
                         .GetFullHtmlFieldId(string.Empty)
                         .Replace("[", "_")
                         .Replace("]", "_") + DateTime.Now.Millisecond.ToString()
        })
    .Value(Model > DateTime.MinValue? Model : DateTime.Today)
)
```

This is my View

```
@Html.EditorFor(model=>Model.EndDate)
```

though This brings the value calender Icon but 
when I click on Icon or text box it wont show the calender to pick date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey I could fix my problem.
just use below line to have the bind date to Telerik DatePiker and this works

```
 @(Html.Telerik().DatePickerFor(model=>Model.Date))
```